# Reorder the top menu items

Tags: content-hub

I want to reorder the top menu items. Is it possible?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the content Hub follow below -

1. On the menu bar, click Manage Icon. [image]
2. On the Manage page, click Pages.

[image]

3. Reorder pages as per your requirement by drag and drop using icon [image]

[image]

4. Then refresh the page you will notice the changes.